# GraphQL mutation in KeystoneJS: "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in undefined"

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, keystonejs

In a KeystoneJS GraphQL project I'm trying to create a new data object (an "Article") in the 'resolveInput' hook of another, existing, data object (a "Proposal" -- when a Proposal is approved, I create an Article based on that Proposals'data).

This worked fine using the Mongoose adapter, but I've tried to do it using the built in GraphQL API, using `keystone.executeQuery` and I get the following error:

[image]

My Article list has a relationship with one Proposal (I'm leaving out the other fields)

```
fields: {
  proposal: {
                isUnique: false,
                type: fields_1.Relationship,
                ref: 'Proposal',
                access: {
                    create: true,
                    read: true,
                    update: false
                }
            }

}
```

and I create the new Article thus (I'm omitting some code)

```
hooks: {
    resolvedInput: async params => {
        const articleCreateInput = {
                                title: cleanTitle,
                                text: cleanText,
                                visible: HIDDEN,
                                proposal: {
                                    connect: {
                                        id: proposalId
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            const articleCreationResult = await keystone.executeQuery(createArticle, { variables: articleCreateInput });

  }
}
```

As far as I can see this is the correct way to do it, using [connect](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/fields/src/types/relationship/#nested-mutations), connecting an existing item to one you are creating.

My query is

```
const createArticle = `mutation createArticle($data:ArticleCreateInput) {
  createArticle(data:$data) {
    id
    title
    visible
    publishDate
  }
} `;
```

and as far as I can see I'm following the schema correctly

[image]

I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake but at the moment I don't see it -- and I'm not sure whether that mistake is a GraphQL mistake or a KeystoneJS mistake (or both).

Comment: check query arguments (variables) - is `articleCreateInput` properly defined

Comment: It works fine from the playground...

Comment: ... but in code ... logged before `executeQuery`?

Comment: @xadm It's `{
  title: 'This is the new thing',
  text: 'abcdefh',
  visible: 'hidden',
  proposal: { connect: { id: '5e5e74c2ddd03b71b42281a8' } }
}`

Comment: relation? one to one?

Comment: is there (article) only one relation ? ... doesn't make sense when working in playground .. open an issue on keystone github - it looks like `executeQuery` fails

Comment: Yes, that is, an Article has 0 or 1 Proposals (the Article can be created via the AdminUI or via the hook we're discussing -- in the latter case a proposal is added to it).  It should be 1-to-1 since I didn't specify 'many', right?  This is the code for the Article Proposal field:
    `proposal: {
    isUnique: false,
    type: Relationship,
    ref: 'Proposal',
    access: {
     create: true,
     read: true,
     update: false
    }
   }`
  It's not `unique` because it may be `null` (or `undefined`) if the Article is created thru AdminUI and it complained if `unique` was true

Comment: @xadm -- I did open an issue

Comment: Github issue mentionned by @Cerulean https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/2595

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble and my problem was that I was sending the variables of the query like this:

`{var1: 'val1', var2: 'val2'}`

instead of

`{data: {var1: 'val1', var2: 'val2'}}`